# Setting Dynamic Properties in Dataproc Job

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Here's what I am trying to accomplish.  I want to create a workflow template so that I can spin up a cluster, run a job, and delete the cluster.  Within the job, I want to pass in properties that can be set dynamically.  For example, set a property to the current date.

Below is a simple example.  I uses the data function correctly but that is handled at creation time so it looks like it will always be 12/31/2020 if I setup the workflow today.  I know I can delete the job and add it back to the template for each run, but I was was hoping for a simpler way.

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create workflow-mk-test --region us-east1 --project data-engineering-doz4

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster workflow-mk-test \
--cluster-name=cluster-mk-test \
--project data-engineering-doz4 \
--image-version=1.3-ubuntu18 \
--bucket data-engineering-dev \
--region us-east1 \
--subnet ml-data-engineering-east1 \
--no-address \
--zone us-east1-b \
--master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--master-boot-disk-size 15 \
--num-workers 2 \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 15

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark gs://data-engineering-dev/jobs/millard-test.py \
--workflow-template=workflow-mk-test \
--step-id=test-job \
--region=us-east1 \
--project=data-engineering-doz4 \
-- date `date -v -1d '+%Y/%m/%d'` \
 --output-location s3n://missionlane-data-engineering-dev-us-east-1/delete-me/`date -v -1d '+%Y/%m/%d'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic properties generated by running shell commands is not a supported feature of Dataproc jobs. In this case, you might want to consider making the logic part of your job, i.e., getting the current date dynamically in `millard-test.py`.

Comment: What about pulling values from Spark or environment variables?